# function definition in BNF C grammar

Tags: c, compiler-construction, grammar, bnf

I'm reading [this](https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm) C BNF grammar. I have the following questions:

1. Is correct which it's `<declarator>` job to parse this syntax: `id(int a, int b)` (in `<direct-declarator>`) and so on to arrays in parameters of a function prototype/definition, etc;
2. In `<function-definition>`, why is `<declarator>` followed by a `{<declaration>}*` ?
   from what I understood, it could make valid a type name or storage class followed by a function header like `id(int a, int b) int`. But I'm sure it isn't valid in C. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, `<declarator>` in that grammar is the name of the object being declared, plus its arguments or array size (and also the pointer qualifiers of its type). `<declarator>` does not include the base type (return type for a function; element type for an array).
2. Note that there are two alternatives in `<direct-declarator>`, both of which seem relevant to functions:

   `<direct-declarator> ( <parameter-type-list> )
   <direct-declarator> ( {<identifier>}* )`

   The first of these is what we normally think of as a function declaration, where the parameters are types or types-with-parameter-name. The second one is just a list of identifiers. (It should, I think, be a comma-separated list of identifiers.) The second case is the old-style "K&R" function definition syntax, which you may never have seen before, and should immediately forget about after reading this answer because -- while C compilers still accept it -- it has been deprecated for not just years, but decades. So *don't use it*. For historical completeness, here's how it looked:

   `int foo(n, p)
       int n;
       char p;
   {
        / Body of the function */
   }`

Comment: It's for K&R support. Now it makes sense to me. About the link I just noticied later. I'm sorry, I'll edit my post